# How to get lm object from list of coefficients and intercept in R

Tags: r

I have a list of coefficients with intercept and I would like to create a R lm object from these. Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: That seems a bit counterintuitive, but maybe you could explain what your final goal is? What would you do with the `lm` object once created?

Comment: Yeah, I know. In a publication, coefficients and intercept are given. I would like to recreate and use this model.

Comment: Use the model how? An `lm` object has quite a bunch of things in it - it sounds like you don't really need it.

Comment: I would like to make predictions on my own data. The coefficents are in table form and about 500 I hoped I could create the model in a somewhat automatic way

Comment: If you look at an actual `lm` object, you can see that it carries quite a few things around, but if you look at the code for `predict.lm`, it probably doesn't need the whole object. I do think though it would be easier to create your own function to match the columns and multiply in order to create predictions.

Comment: Have transferred my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use y = intercept + slope * x if we know intercept and slope and x is some value for which we want to know y.  (If we have more than one predictor it works similarly.)

The above is so simple we don't really need an `lm` object to do it but if you really want an `lm` object anyways then since a line is determined by two points we can use these two which follow from the equation above.

- x = 0, y = intercept
- x = 1, y = intercept + slope

so using those `fm` below is the required `lm` object. (If we have multiple predictors then consider the point where they are all 0 and the points where exactly one of them is 1 and the rest are 0.)

```
intercept <- 1; slope <- 2 # test data

y <- c(intercept, intercept + slope)
x <- 0:1

fm <- lm(y ~ x)

coef(fm)
## (Intercept)          x1          x2 
##           1           2           3 

# suppose we want to know y given x = 3. Here are two ways.

predict(fm, list(x = 3))
## 1 
## 7 

intercept + slope * 3
## [1] 7
```

Here is an example with multiple predictors:

```
b <- 1:3 # test data

# 1st row of X is all 0's; remaining rows each have one 1 and rest 0    
X <- diag(length(b))[, -1]
colnames(X) <- paste0("x", seq(ncol(X))) # x1, x2
y <- b[1] + c(0, b[-1])    
DF <- data.frame(y, X)
fm <- lm(y ~ ., DF)

predictors <- c(x1 = 3, x2 = 10)

predict(fm, as.list(predictors))
##  1 
## 37 

sum(b * c(1, predictors))
## [1] 37
```

### Updated

Have updated several times.